# How to update column value via for statement in Python?

Tags: python, pandas, for-loop, google-api

I want to input language code using Google API.
I ran the below code, however all values in the language column input the same.
It seems the final line had an error because the values ​​of all rows are being updated with the code value of the last row.
How can I correct this code?

```
for row in row_list:
    for column in column_list:
        detectText = str(df02.loc[row, column]).strip()
        if detectText != 'nan':
            print(df02.loc[row, column])
            detect_text = detect_language(detectText)
            df02.loc[row]['language'] = detect_text
```

Below is my expected output

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First dont [use loops](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16476924/how-to-iterate-over-rows-in-a-dataframe-in-pandas) if exist some alternatives, e.g.:

```
df02['language']  = df02['Text'].dropna().astype(str).str.strip().apply(detect_language)
```

Answer (score 1):

I switched to the following code, also expected output came out.

```
df02.loc[row, 'language'] = detect_text
```